# Raspberry Pi + JDK1.8.0_151 + JavaFX + BlueJ

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, bluej, java-8

After installing JDK1.8.0_151 and JavaFX Embedded SDK 8.60.9 on a Raspberry Pi 3 I upgraded from BlueJ 3.1.7 to 4.1.2.

Then I permitted the "write" access to the inputs to avoid error messages referring to this.

At the next start of BlueJ I got the following:

- message "Cannot open display"
- > exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Property javafx.embed.singleThread is not supported

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the incorrect installation of the packages.To fix it try this:~
First run

sudo apt-get update
Then run the install commands.

This will add all the available packages to your package index. Then your package manager will be able to find the packages in the index, and so install them.

if the error in the packages then it will be rectified.

Comment: The latest version of BlueJ in the repository for the Raspberry Pi is 3.1.7, because the versions 4.x.x require minimum Java8_60 and JavaFX, which is not supported from the Raspberry Pi.
From this reason the command sudo apt-get update has no effect.